# Manually Trigger Flutter Hot Reload/Full Restart with HTTP/CURL requests to the Observatory server

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, hot-reload

I am trying to develop a UI to control the project development and workflow but I am not able to trigger Hot Reload or Restart.

Is there a way of **manually triggering the Hot Reload/Full Restart** using **HTTP/CURL** request to the observatory dart server on http://127.0.0.1:8888/ when running the command `flutter run --observatory-port 8888 --disable-service-auth-codes lib/main.dart`?

Comment: what do you need `--observatory-port` for? cannot you just use `SIGUSR1` / `SIGUSR2` signals? for more see `--pid-file` switch

Comment: Thank you @pskink. How can I use SIGURS1 and 2?

Comment: maybe this will be better: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/doc/daemon.md